# Dynamic Menus in NavigationView

Tags: android, navigationview

I have this Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The ActionBar -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>
```

So, looking that in `NavigationView` we have the attribute:

```
  app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
```

And I have this XML id menu folder.

I wanna make dynamic menus, ie, in code I should mount the 'MenuItem' objects and set into `NavigationView`.

Is this correct?
Is this best pratice?
Is this possible?

Note: My code is working with 'static drawer_menu', I want to improve it.

I'm waiting.

**[EDIT]**

I make it:

```
 Menu menu = nvDrawer.getMenu();
        for (KSMenuItem kmi : menus.values()) {
            if (menu.size() == 0) {
                menu.add(kmi.getId());
            }
            if (menu.getItem(kmi.getId()) == null) {
                menu.add(kmi.getId());
            }
            MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(kmi.getId());
            mi.setIcon(kmi.getIcon());
            mi.setTitle(kmi.getTittle());
        }
```

But this error happened:

> 06-27 15:26:15.538  15335-15335/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.sticdev30.newdrawer, PID: 15335
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sticdev30.newdrawer/com.example.sticdev30.newdrawer.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

KSMenuItem is a POJO with my menu data. In kmi.id I informed incremental integers...

I'm waitning

Comment: checkout my answer over here :http://stackoverflow.com/a/30706233/3544839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `kmi.getId()` returns `int`(or `long`).

But [Menu.add(int)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int)) adds menu with title from the given string resources, which is usually represented as `R.string.something`, and not for usual integer values.

[Menu.add(CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(java.lang.CharSequence)) does add menu with title of CharSequence, so you need to do some int-to-string conversion like `menu.add(kmi.getId() + "");`

Answer (score 35):

You can re-inflate `NavigationView`at runtime with 2 lines of code using public method `inflateMenu`. In this example i re-inflate with `new_navigation_drawer_items.xml`

```
navigationView.getMenu().clear(); //clear old inflated items.
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.new_navigation_drawer_items); //inflate new items.
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can add menus dynamically by following steps :

Step1. Obtain menu object from Navigation View [NavigationView.getMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#getMenu%28%29)

Step2. Add any item to the menu using [Menu.add()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: The method [Menu.add(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int)) expects a string resource id. From the logs checkout fifth line it says resource(String resource) not found.

Answer (score 3):

We can dynamically add/remove menu items.
Suppose we have this menu items `

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@mipmap/home_icon_x48"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_part_catalouge"
        android:icon="@mipmap/catalogue_icon_x48"
        android:title="Parts Catalogue" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_favourite"
        android:icon="@mipmap/my_favourate_x48"
        android:title="My-Favourite" />\
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_opencarrequest"
        android:icon="@mipmap/cart_request"
        android:title="Cart-Request" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
        android:icon="@mipmap/settings_x48"
        android:title="Settings" />
</group>


<item android:title="">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@mipmap/logout_icon_x48"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

`

In Activity we can add or remove menuitems based on our condition

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// your activity layout here
   NavigationView navigationView= (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); // navigation view which holds menu items
   navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
   if(yourCondition){
          navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setVisible(false); //if you want to hide first item
          navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setVisible(true); // if you want to show second menu item should be visible
  }


}
```

Hope it will help.