# Android Navigation Drawer - how to add dynamic content?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Please help with adding dynamic content into my existing navigation drawer. This is how my activity layout looks now:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xxx.HomeActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/stadium_bg"
    android:id="@+id/xxx_ayout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NagivationView uses drawer_view in order to display static content in menu. So, the drawer_view.xml looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/leagues_in_progress_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_line_spacing_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_leagues_in_progress" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/last_matches_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_alarm_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_last_matches" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/archive_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder_open_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_archive" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/put_score_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_put_score" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

My wish is to add dynamic items into new item group, right below static content. In a static way this should be resolved like below, but how to build it dynamically?

```
<item android:title="Sub items">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
            android:title="Sub item 1" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
            android:title="Sub item 2" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

In Activity code nothing special happens. Just something like:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xxx);

        this.mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.pinokioLayout);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        this.mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name
        );
        this.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this.mDrawerToggle);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        this.setupDrawerContent(navigationView);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            this.displayMenuFragment(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
        }
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) 
    {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        displayMenuFragment(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695038/how-to-programmatically-add-a-submenu-item-to-the-new-material-design-android-su

Comment: Thanks @Renjith. Works well.

Comment: Check my answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/33072681/1050058](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33072681/1050058)