# How to get the id of Sub Menu in Navigation view

Tags: android, android-navigation, navigationview

I have implemented new Navigation view in navigation drawer. Now I want to hide and show the logout menu item on several login and logout condition.

here is my menu item of navigation view

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawer_ic_home"
        android:title="@string/home_string" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/offer_coffee"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawer_ic_offer_coffee"
        android:title="@string/offer_coffee_string" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/share_coffee"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawer_ic_share_coffee"
        android:title="@string/share_coffee_string" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/take_coffee"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawer_ic_take_coffee"
        android:title="@string/take_coffee_string" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/offer_status"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawer_ic_coffee"
        android:title="@string/offer_status"
        />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/about_us"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawer_ic_about_us"
        android:title="@string/about_us_string" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="@string/logout" />

</group>
```

I want to hide the Logout item if I am not login and if I am login then I want to show this sub menu.

I have seen several links but they all are working on group of items but in my case I have to access single sub menu item named Logout in the group .

Comment: It doesn't seem right. Navigation Drawer is basically a `ListView` and the code you have put above is for the toolbar menu. Are you sure you have put the correct code here?

Comment: its a new desing pattern of navigation view , see here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695038/how-to-programmatically-add-a-submenu-item-to-the-new-material-design-android-su

Answer (score 3):

The whole menu is indexed from `0` to `n` from top to bottom. So you have two groups with 5 item each then it is from 0 to 9.

```
private boolean ifNotLoggedIn;
private NavigationView navigationView;

...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        if(ifNotLoggedIn){
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(7).setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

As @Moinkhan pointed out, we can use the `findById()` method as well to do the similar.

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);
```

Comment: +1 vote up .. for your ans .. but its not good practise to use index position while we can use it by item Id ..

Comment: this was giving me error 
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(7).setVisible(false);

Answer (score 2):

It's simple just add the following code.

I am assuming that you are taking `isUserLoggedIn` boolean variable to store user login state.

`navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav);
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
if (! isUserLoggedIn) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for helping me , I was doing exactly both same things answered above.
but some how I managed to do it in different way and that is to get the tile of the menu item clicked and then comparing it , if the item title is logout , and if I am logged in (As per my case ) do what ever I want.