# How to programmaticallly remove submenu from navigation drawer in Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am developing an Android app. Firstly, let me tell you that I am not professional. What I am doing now is I am adding submenu to menu depending on a condition. But I need to do it very often in my app. But my problem is I added a submenu to the menu as first time.

But second time when I update menu depending on condition, existing submenu is not removed and new submenu is appended to navigation drawer. How can I remove submenu that is programmatically added to menu? Why my code is not removing it?

Here is my code

```
public void updateAuthUI()
    {
        isLoggedIn = tempStorage.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_is_logged_in),false);
        Menu menu = leftDrawer.getMenu();
        menu.removeItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.logout_item_id));
        menu.removeItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.login_item_id));
        menu.removeItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.register_item_id));
        SubMenu authSubMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Auth");

        if(isLoggedIn)
        {
            authSubMenu.add(1,getResources().getInteger(R.integer.logout_item_id),99,"Sign out");
        }
        else{
            authSubMenu.add(1,getResources().getInteger(R.integer.register_item_id),97,"Register");
            authSubMenu.add(1,getResources().getInteger(R.integer.login_item_id),98,"Sign in").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    openLoginActivity();
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of my problem

[image]

As you can see Auth submenu is appended without removing existing one.

Comment: MenuItem item = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3);
item.setVisible(false); may this one solve your problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695038/how-to-programmatically-add-a-submenu-item-to-the-new-material-design-android-su

Comment: Just setting visiblity is not good for performance. It will consume so on memory.

Comment: navigationView.getMenu().clear(); //clear old inflated items.
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.new_navigation_drawer_items);  or you can clear it than recreate

Comment: Remove previously added SubMenu by calling menu.removeItem(R.id.registerId), then add new SubMenu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
authSubMenu.clear();
```

before your first

```
authSubMenu.add();
```

I just used `SubMenu.clear()` in an Android app where I was using a third-party library, and I needed to clear out an unwanted submenu from the action bar. (I actually wanted to remove the submenu completely, and this was the only way I could find to do it. It seemed to work.)

That's different from your situation, where `authSubMenu` is a menu you just added via `menu.addSubMenu("Auth")`, so you would expect it to be empty. But, as you've seen, it apparently isn't empty: rather, [`addSubMenu("Auth")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#addSubMenu(java.lang.CharSequence)) returns the existing submenu of that title. (I can't find documentation to that effect; I'm just going by the results you've reported.)

If that really is the case, as it appears to be, then `authSubMenu.clear()` will remove all existing items from the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

As @slymm said in a comment you can remove all menu and submenu items using

```
navigationView.getMenu().clear();
```

This can be used to remove submenu (and menu elements) and then recreate them  with the new required items

Comment: That will remove main menu in Navigatio view. Not sub menu.

Comment: Yes you are right sorry, I wanted to say the menu and submenus. Rereading your question I see you only want to remove the submenu items, what about clearing the menu and recreate the submenu elements?