# hide menu activity_main drawer via TextView

Tags: android

In `MainActivity` I have `TextView` "role" with value "Karyawan" or "Manajer". I want to hide a menu in `activity_main_drawer` if user login Role as "Karyawan".

my code :

```
 private void hideItem() {
    if (role.getText().toString().equals("Karyawan")) {
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.user_list).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

But, code above not working when I put it on `OnCreate`.

Comment: can you try `nav_Menu.remove()`

Comment: no method nav_Menu.remove()

Comment: You can try `nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.user_list).clear()`.

Comment: @KeLiuyue no method `nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.user_list).clear()`

Comment: @DekiKurniaHadiPermana I found the method in this link,[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867056/how-to-programmaticallly-remove-submenu-from-navigation-drawer-in-android/38283379#38283379](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867056/how-to-programmaticallly-remove-submenu-from-navigation-drawer-in-android/38283379#38283379)

Comment: @KeLiuyue that is for NavigationView not for Menu