# Replicate Google Keep "Add Label" in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, navigation-drawer, google-keep

I tried to look for a question like this here but couldn't find one.

I'm trying to implement something like Google Keep's "Add Label" in my Navigation Drawer and make that category stay permanently. I think the last part can be done with SharedPreferences. It's just the first I need help with. Any ideas as to how I can implement something similar? Or any examples I can take a look at? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method to add items:
[dynamically add items to Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695038/how-to-programmatically-add-a-submenu-item-to-the-new-material-design-android-su)

Now it depends in what kind of dialog you want the user to enter them.