# Xamarin.Android : Add the dynamic menu items to Navigation view of DrawerLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I followed [this](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Cheesesquare) sample to design the Navigation menu view using android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.

My Static Menu item list defined in **drawer_menuList.xml** as :

```
 <group
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:icon="@drawable/item1"
            android:title="Item1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Item2"
            android:icon="@drawable/item2"
            android:title="Item2"/>
    </group>
```

**activity_main.axml** :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menuList" />
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695038/how-to-programmatically-add-a-submenu-item-to-the-new-material-design-android-su) similar thread on stack overflow and tried this :

```
NavigationView mDrawerList = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);

Menu menu = mDrawerList.getMenu();
```

I am not getting any `getMenu()`/`GetMenu()` method in xamarin.android. Can anyone suggest the right way to add the menu along with the icons dynamically in NavigationView of DrawerLayout.

Comment: .Menu, usually the way Xamarin approach the 'getX' is to convert it to a property

Comment: getX : It returns the visual x position of the view. But as per android document getMenu(), returns the Menu instance associated with this navigation view. I need this not the visual coordinate position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering to my question :

Suppose you have a list of Menu items such as :

```
List<MenuItems> lst = new List<MenuItems>();
lst = GetMenuItems();
```

Then in xamarin we can dynamically populate the Menu items with their title and icon as :

```
NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
    foreach (MenuItems objMenuItems in lst)
      {
         int iconID = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(objMenuItems.IconName).GetValue(null);

         navigationView.Menu.Add(objMenuItems.Title).SetIcon(iconID);
      }
```

By this way you can dynamically add the menu items in NavigationView of DrawerLayout.

Comment: Good answer dear :)!